# How to search for files with a specific permission

Tags: 12.04, search

How can I search for files that have a specific permission. For example, I have 10000 files and I want to find the ones that have the READ ONLY flag. In another case I want to search for another that has a particular owner. Or in another to see the files that are READ ONLY and EXECUTABLE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use the `find` command, which allows you to recursively search through the directory tree. For example, if you particularly wanted to find files that were read-only, you could type

```
find <specify location> -type f -perm -444
```

For files belonging to a particular user you could use

```
find <location> -type f -user mike
```

For files executable (for all) you could use

```
find <location> -type f -perm -777
```

For those that are executable and read-only for all you would use 555 in place of 777 in the example above. You can also search for files that belong to a group by substituting `-user mike` for `-group mike`.

To negate the search terms and so search for the exact opposite, you can use an exclamation mark like this:

```
find <location> -type f ! -perm -444
```

Note: Specifying a dash before the permissions (e.g. `-perm -444`) means that all files that have a read only flag will be found and not just those that are 444; to search for 444 exactly and only that, simply remove the dash (e.g. `-perm 444`).

Note2: Combinations of permissions can be sought as well using `-a` for and and `-o` for or; for example to find exactly these permissions, type:

```
find <location> -type f -perm 744 -o -perm 666
```

Directories can be searched for with `-type d`.

See `man find` for the other available permutations.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about difference between `-444` and `444`

Comment: For me, `-perm -444` finds files that has the `read` permission, not those that are read-only (meaning, having _only_ `read` and no other permissions).